# The parameters project.build.directory for goal '... myMojo' are missing or invalid

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have made a maven plugin that uses the following expression to find the target folder.

It runs fine (locally) on maven 3.1.0. It fails on my jenkins build server with maven 3.0.4.

Is there any expression that would be compatible with both maven versions?

```
/**
 * Location of the output directory.
 *
 * @parameter property="project.build.directory"
 * @required
 */
@SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
private File outputDirectory;
```

Comment: The correct way would be `@Parameter( defaultValue = "${project.build.directory}")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Have you tried proper maven 3.x annotations ?

```java
/**
 * Location of the output directory.
 *
 * @required
 **/
@Parameter( property = "project.build.directory")
private File outputDirectory;
```

From  http://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-annotations/index.html

1. or does that work better ?

```java
/** 
 * Location of the output directory.
 *
 * @parameter expression="${project.build.directory}"
 */
private File outputDirectory;
```

Comment: I used to have 'expression' tag but is has been deprecated in 3.1. I will try org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Parameter.

Comment: I cannot find information about the deprecation in the release notes. The official guide (http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html) still references them and the expression evaluator is still there: http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.0/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugin/PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.html